# Trying to repeatedly read input goes wrong

Tags: c++, io

I have been desperately trying to figure this out, but just can't find a solution that works. My C++ knowledge is limited, so my code is probably a mess as well.

What I want to achieve:

- Ask user for input
- check if the input is *equal* to either 1, 2 or 3
- If the previous check fails, prompt the user again until valid input has been entered.

My current code:
I have tried several solutions and combinations thereof, so the current state probably does not make much sense:
 `

```
void execute()
{
    printf("Waiting for input:");
    while(true) {
        char buffer[10];
        char input[10];

        if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
            sscanf(buffer, "%s", input);

            if (!strcmp(input, "1") || !strcmp(input, "2") || !strcmp(input, "3")) {
                varKey = input[0] - '0';
                return;
            }
            else {
                printf("Invalid input, try again (1, 2, or 3):");
            }
        }
        //std::cin.sync();
        //std::cin.clear();
        //std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        flushBuffer();
    }
}

void flushBuffer()
{
   int c;
   while(c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

For context:
The main function `execute()` gets called repeatedly, but for each iteration everything is completely reset. (as if you would start the application for the first time)

Current situation:

- 'Happy flow' works perfectly. As long as the user inserts valid input, the 
  application works exactly as intended.
- Once I enter invalid input, I get prompted again but have to press the `return` key twice, and the input is not correctly validated.

Hopefully the screenshot provides some more clarity as to what goes wrong.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1UWI.png)

Comment: Why don't you simply use the functions from the [c++ I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)?

Comment: There is a problem of operator precedence in `flushBuffer`. It's better and clearer to use
               `c = getchar();
  while ((c != '\n') && (c != EOF))
  {
   c = getchar();
  }`

Comment: As @GiliLevy said, there is indeed something wrong with the precedence, although I can't completely explain it since something of the following would work:
`int c=5;
    if(c = 4 != 4){
        std::cout << "C==5" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "C==4" << std::endl;
    }`
Anyway, I would use `fflush(stdin)` instead of `flushBuffer()` to save the trouble.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I tried to dig a little deeper into specific c++ solutions, and have finally found something that works. Thanks!

Comment: @GiliLevy @GoldenSpecOps, usage of `fflush(stdin)` or changes to `flushBuffer()` did not yield different results. But I managed to find a solution. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, being the complete beginner I am, I probably mashed a bunch of different approaches into one which (non-)surprisingly didn't work out.

This thread did the trick for me: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/.

This is my resulting code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
void execute()
{
    std::cout << "Waiting for input: ";
    while(true) {
        int value = 0;
        std::string input;

        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::stringstream myStream(input);

        //Try to convert input to integer
        if (myStream >> value) {
           if(value == 1 || value == 2 || value == 3) {
               varKey = value;
               return;
           }
        }
        std::cout << "Invalid input, try again (1, 2, or 3): ";
    }
}
```